# Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$ invertible for $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, inverse-function

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, where $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$.

If you work out the inverse of $f$, you get $f^{-1} = \frac{1}{y} - 1$.

However, I'm confused about the role of the domain and codomain here. Clearly $f$ maps from all $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ to all $\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$. Note that $f$ does not map to $0$, even though it's in the definition of the function.

$f^{-1}$ maps from $\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Note that $f^{-1}$ does not map $0$.

My question is: under these conditions, do we consider $f$ invertible? The definition of $f$ states that its codomain is all the nonnegative reals. In practice, $f$ maps only to the positive reals. When we consider the domain of $f^{-1}$, is that the nonnegative reals or the positive reals? If the former, then $f$ is not invertible since $f^{-1}(0)$ doesn't work; if the latter, then $f$ is invertible.

Comment: Being technically precise, the function $f$ is injective (one-to-one) but not surjective (onto). As such, from injectivity, $f$ has an inverse function _with respect to its image_. So if we restrict the codomain to that of the image of $f$, then yes it is invertible. Since $f$ is not surjective, it is _not invertible_ as a whole. This is more of an argument in lingo than it is in an argument in practical purposes.

Comment: $f$ does not map "to all $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$", but to $(0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, everything depends on how you want to define $f$. If you consider $f$ as you wrote it, it is not invertible since the inverse at $x=0$ does not exist. However, if you restrict the codomain, it will be invertible.